# dplyr merge two datasets for Finished Goods Sales and Bill of Materials

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on an analysis of need for raw materials in my company and the approach i am taking is to use the sales records of finished goods to combine with bill of materials for each finished goods. The problem i am having now that each finished product consists of multiple components, and many finished products share common components. I am trying to keep all individual sales record for each finished good and use the UnitsSold to multiply with the unit qty for each component to get the demand of raw materials. Here is code for sample datasets:

```
fg_Sales <- data_frame(FG_PartNumber=rep(c("A","B","C"),2),
                       Order_Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2011-1-1"),as.Date("2012-1-10"),length.out = 6),
                       FG_UnitsSold=c(100,200,300,400,500,600))

bill_materials <- data_frame(FG_PartNumber=rep(c("A","B","C"),4),
                             Components=c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C7","C7","C8","C8","C9"),
                             Qty=rnorm(3,1,n = 12))%>%
                             arrange(FG_PartNumber)
```

i am familiar with left_join in dplyr but it seems not work because it would always give me with the first component for each finished product.

Can anyone kindly help with this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not understanding the question, but if you group your two data frames by the `FG_PartNumber` and make a pivot tables on the quantities you are interested in, you can get the the totals you are looking for:

```
    #Create data
    set.seed(1)
      fg_Sales <- data_frame(FG_PartNumber=rep(c("A","B","C"),2),
                           Order_Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2011-1-1"),as.Date("2012-1-10"),length.out = 6),
                           FG_UnitsSold=c(100,200,300,400,500,600))

    bill_materials <- data_frame(FG_PartNumber=rep(c("A","B","C"),4),
                                 Components=c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C7","C7","C8","C8","C9"),
                                 Qty=rnorm(3,1,n = 12))%>%
      arrange(FG_PartNumber)

    library(dplyr)
#make pivot tables for sales and quantity

    tot_sales <- fg_Sales %>%
      group_by(FG_PartNumber) %>%
      summarise(tot_sales = sum(FG_UnitsSold))

    tot_materials <- bill_materials %>%
      group_by(FG_PartNumber) %>%
      summarise(tot_qty = sum(Qty))

#join the pivot tables together    
    df <- left_join(tot_sales, tot_materials)

> df
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  FG_PartNumber tot_sales  tot_qty
          <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1             A       500 13.15087
2             B       700 14.76326
3             C       900 11.30953
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `inner_join` from `dplyr` is the best choice here:

```
library(dplyr)
fg_Sales_ext <- inner_join(x = fg_Sales,
                           y = bill_materials,
                           by = "FG_PartNumber")
```

From the `inner_join` documentation: "If there are multiple matches between x and y, all combination of the matches are returned."

With `fg_Sales_ext` you can perform any kind of analysis now with `group_by` and `summarise`.

Comment: Hi evgeniC, that's exactly what i need. Thanks for your help!